# how to launch dx app using createProcess()

Tags: c++, process, directx

using this code snippet:

```
STARTUPINFO          si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
char                 szExe[] = "C:\\Apps\\Desktop\\Release\\simplesample.exe";
//char szExe[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

if(CreateProcess(0, szExe, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
{
    // optionally wait for process to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hThread, 0);  

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
return 0;
```

when I use notepad.exe, notepad gets launched.

However, when I use the path to simplesample.exe, it launches simplesample and crashes immediately. I fail to understand why simplesample won't launch properly from createProcess.

I can launch simplesample.exe from command prompt as is.

PS: `Simplesample` is a dx sample app using winmain

Answer (score 0):

Ty to pass directory where `simplesample.exe` is to `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter of [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Probably, this program searches for assets, shaders or DLLs in current folder, but receives directory of calling process and thus it cannot find them.

From [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *lpCurrentDirectory [in, optional]*
>
> The full path to the current directory for the process. The string can also specify a UNC path.
>
> *If this parameter is NULL, the new process will have the same current drive and directory as the calling process*. (This feature is
>   provided primarily for shells that need to start an application and
>   specify its initial drive and working directory.)